# PHP checking how many times to query

Tags: php

I have a calendar that has to mark-up taken dates. For example I have 2 records with two dates one is from `2018-06-01` to `2018-06-05` and the other is from `2018-06-13` to `2018-06-16` and they keep duplicating the dates basing on how many rows there are in the database. How do I make all the rows show? Here is how the problem looks:

http://prntscr.com/jqjqie

And this is the query that I use to display the dates. So how do I make it show all the taken dates but not with the duplicating bug?

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM booking_2 ORDER BY book2_id");
$result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
$eventNum = $result->num_rows;
if ($eventNum > 0){
    $previousDate = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $date_from = $row['date_from'];
        $date_to = $row['date_to'];
        $time_from = strtotime($date_from);
        $time_fromm = idate('d', $time_from);
        $time_to = strtotime($date_to);
        $time_too = idate('d', $time_to);
        if (date("Y-m-d", $time_from) != date("Y-m-d", $previousDate)){
            if ($currentDate >= $time_from && $currentDate <= $time_to){
                echo '<li id="' . $row['book2_id'] . '" style="background-color:#FF3232 !important;" date="' . $currentDate . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . $dayCount . '</span>';
            }else{
                echo '<li date="' . $currentDate . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . $dayCount . '</span>';
            }
        }

        $previousDate = $time_from;
    }
}else{
    echo '<li date="' . $currentDate . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . $dayCount . '</span>';
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to GROUP BY in your sql query...

Comment: Okay I will have to look into it. thanks. Do I have to select specific columns then? or can i still use SELECT *?

Comment: You can use `SELECT *`, but actually one rarely wants to do that. Take a look at a few examples.

Comment: Yeah, well I have read manuals and viewed examples still does not work unfortunately. Maybe I am wrong on some aspect. Are you sure that this solution requires GROUP BY?

Comment: Loos to me from your description. However since I cannot see the screenshot you posted (it appears to be broken) I don't want to insist...

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/jqjqie) even now?